# GORM save() on Grails is not saving in the DB

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a list of objects that I need to save, I have this function

```
private saveAll(List<Element> elements){
    for(Element element: elements){
        element.save(flush:true, insert:true)
    }
}
```

I the element class (groovy class) is like the following:

```
@ToString(excludes = 'metaClass,content', includePackage = false, includeNames = false)
class Element {

    Integer id
    MessageSourceType sourceType
    String key
    String valueEN
    String valueDE
    String valueES
    String valueFR
    String valueIT
    String valuePT
    String valueAR
    String valueCMN
    String valueHI
    String valuePL

    static constraints = {
        sourceType nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 256
        key nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 254, unique:true
        valueEN nullable: true, maxSize: 64000
        valueDE nullable: true, maxSize: 64000
        valueES nullable: true, maxSize: 64000
        valueFR nullable: true, maxSize: 64000
        valueIT nullable: true, maxSize: 64000
        valuePT nullable: true, maxSize: 64000
        valueAR nullable: true, maxSize: 64000
        valueCMN nullable: true, maxSize: 64000
        valueHI nullable: true, maxSize: 64000
        valuePL nullable: true, maxSize: 64000
    }

    static mapping = {
        table "element"
        id column: "eId"
        version column: "eVersion"
        sourceType column: "eSourceType"
        valueEN column: "eValueEN"
        valueDE column: "eValueDE"
        valueES column: "eValueES"
        valueFR column: "eValueFR"
        valueIT column: "eValueIT"
        valuePT column: "eValuePT"
        valueAR column: "eValueAR"
        valueCMN column: "eValueCMN"
        valueHI column: "eValueHI"
        valuePL column: "eValuePL"
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object element){
        if(element != null && element instanceof Element){
            if(this.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(((Element)element).getKey())){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

on every save I get the following log:

```
2017-11-25 16:38:56,787 | TRACE |  | localhost-startStop-1 | org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor | executing insertions
2017-11-25 16:38:56,787 | DEBUG |  | localhost-startStop-1 | org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor | executing identity-insert immediately
```

but then when I check the table in the DB I find it empty, no insertions is reflected. I don't understand why would no error is raised, or why the data is not saved in the data base

Can you please check if I have any problem in the code (I am a groovy/grails newbie)  or guide me why would a behaviour like this happen?

Comment: There are any number of reasons this might happen.  One is that something is rolling the transaction back later.  Validation might be failing (you can rule that one out by including `failOnError: true` when calling `.save(...)`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I have added the failOnError set to true and added as attribute to the save method but no errors were logged!

Comment: `failOnError` wouldn't necessarily cause anything to be logged but if no exception was thrown that indicates that validation did not fail.  Without seeing an example project, it may be difficult to answer your question.  As I said before, there are any number of reasons that the data might not be saved and just `element.save(flush:true, insert:true)` isn't enough to diagnose the problem.  Sorry that I cannot help.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

try this and see if you are getting any kind of error:

```
private saveAll(List<Element> elements){
    for(Element element: elements){
        element.validate()
        if (element.hasErrors()) {
            element.errors.allErrors.each {
               println it
           }
        } else {
          element.save(flush: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if saveAll is called from the service, remove transactional declaration by adding static property ( `static transactional=false` ) and see if that will make a difference.